# How to encode or write information into MIFARE DESFIRe ev2 that would act as id card with microtransaction functionality

Tags: encoding, smartcard, mifare, desfire

I am new to the smart card encoding or writing.
I need to write employee profile information and balance for microtransaction feature into the card (DESFIRe ev2).
I haven't encounter any practical solution about my problem. Is it required a programming or some software would be sufficient? Either way, it would be very helpful if you can share any knowledge/tutorial about card encoding.

I searched on internet including Youtube, but mostly the videos or websites is about writing a url into a nfc tag.
I am expecting some step by step programming or in the most simple cast a tutorial using a software to encode information and balance into the card.

Comment: I recently wrote a beginner tutorial for Mifare DESFire tags, covering e.g. writing to and reading from a Standard File, available on medium.com: https://medium.com/@androidcrypto/mifare-desfire-ev3-a-beginner-tutorial-android-java-using-the-desfire-for-android-tools-00aaecb8fa93. The full Android/Java source code and a debug apk is included on GitHub. For your task (Micropayments) you need to use a Value File, but it is not too hard to append the code for this file type.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I'm really grateful for your time and effort in writing this tutorial. How can I not find your site up until this time.

Answer (score 0):

First. It is VERY bad idea to put balance on the actual card. This can be manipulated.

The best approach is for the card to carry only an ID (Unique identifier), and when read, the reader device to check with a remote API/Endpoint what is the balance, as well as other sensitive (or personal) information like name, DOB, etc.. and potentially the reader (depending on conditions) to request an update of the balance..
With this approach no actual or PI data is on the card, and the control of who modifying the balance or PI is controlled by the remote API in a single place.

Comment: As NXP designed the Mifare DESFire for (e.g.) Micropayment purposes I won't name it a "very bad idea". You are right, it is always a good idea to use a background server to re-check the balance on the card with a server resource, but then you need to run an (internet) connection between each vendor machine and the server. Think of thousends vendor machines operating in remote areas - how would you solve this problem ? As each read and or write access to a Mifare DESFire file demands an authentication with an AES-128 key it might be ok to use "offline" usage, especially with small amounts.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I agree with you but as @Michael Fehr said the card should be able to operate without the internet to be more convenient, it would be bad if you can't take a bus because there is no internet connection due to bad weather or something like that.